# Change fragment layout's data with button clicked

Tags: android-fragments

[picture of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcA5g.png)

This is the little project I have been working on. The linegraph is drawn from ta data retrieved from sqlite database. Through the spinner, when I click a required year, linegraph should be changed. But the changes cannot be seen. I could not refresh the whole fragment.

```
public class CategoryChart extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{
LineChart chart;
TransactionDatabaseAdapter transactionDatabaseAdapter;
String firstDate=null;
public static CategoryChart getInstance(Context context){
    CategoryChart categoryChart=new CategoryChart();
    Toast.makeText(context, "inside ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return categoryChart;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_category_chart,container,false);
    spinner(view);
    drawChart(view);

    return view;
}





public void spinner(final View view){

    transactionDatabaseAdapter=new TransactionDatabaseAdapter(getActivity());
    final Spinner dropdown= (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayList items=new ArrayList();
    items.add(2015);
    items.add(2014);
    Integer temp= (Integer) items.get(0);
    firstDate = Integer.toString(temp);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,items);
    dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);



    dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View spinnerTextView, int position, long id) {
            TextView myText= (TextView) spinnerTextView;
            firstDate= (String) myText.getText();
             drawChart(getView());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
public void drawChart(View view)
{

    transactionDatabaseAdapter=new TransactionDatabaseAdapter(getContext());

    chart= (LineChart) view.findViewById(R.id.chart);
    chart.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark));

    ArrayList<Entry> entries=new ArrayList<>();
    entries.add(new Entry((float) transactionDatabaseAdapter.getChartData(firstDate,"01"), 0));

    entries.add(new Entry((float) transactionDatabaseAdapter.getChartData(firstDate,"02"), 1));
    entries.add(new Entry((float) transactionDatabaseAdapter.getChartData(firstDate,"03"), 2));
    entries.add(new Entry((float) transactionDatabaseAdapter.getChartData(firstDate,"04"), 3));
    entries.add(new Entry((float) transactionDatabaseAdapter.getChartData(firstDate,"05"), 4));
    entries.add(new Entry((float) transactionDatabaseAdapter.getChartData(firstDate,"06"), 5));
    entries.add(new Entry((float) transactionDatabaseAdapter.getChartData(firstDate,"07"), 6));
    entries.add(new Entry((float) transactionDatabaseAdapter.getChartData(firstDate,"08"), 7));
    entries.add(new Entry((float) transactionDatabaseAdapter.getChartData(firstDate,"09"), 8));
    entries.add(new Entry((float) transactionDatabaseAdapter.getChartData(firstDate,"10"), 9));
    entries.add(new Entry((float) transactionDatabaseAdapter.getChartData(firstDate,"11"), 10));
    entries.add(new Entry((float) transactionDatabaseAdapter.getChartData(firstDate, "12"), 11));

    LineDataSet dataset= new LineDataSet(entries,"# of calls");

    ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    labels.add("January");
    labels.add("February");
    labels.add("March");
    labels.add("April");
    labels.add("May");
    labels.add("June");
    labels.add("July");
    labels.add("August");
    labels.add("September");
    labels.add("October");
    labels.add("November");
    labels.add("December");

    LineData data = new LineData(labels,dataset);
    chart.setData(data);

    chart.setDescription("goo ");
    Toast.makeText(getContext(),firstDate,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Here, linegraph should be changed according to the value of firstDate. Value of firstDate is changed but not layout. Please help

**This is my updated code**

```
 Activity mActivity;

listener mCallback;
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    mActivity=activity;
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mCallback= (listener) mActivity;
}

LineChart chart;
TransactionDatabaseAdapter transactionDatabaseAdapter;
public String firstDate;
Spinner spinner;
Button selectBtn;
public static ArrayList<String> spinnerDate= new ArrayList<String>(){{
    add("2015");
    add("2014");
}};


public static CategoryChart getInstance(String spinnerDate){

    CategoryChart categoryChart=new CategoryChart();
    Bundle args=new Bundle();
    args.putString("dateValue", spinnerDate);
    categoryChart.setArguments(args);

    return categoryChart;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_category_chart, container, false);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    firstDate=bundle.getString("dateValue");
    spinner(view);
    drawChart(view);
    return view;
}



public void spinner(final View view){

    spinner= (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spinnerDate);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View spinnerTextView, int position, long id) {
            String pass= String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem());
            mCallback.firstDateBack(pass);

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }

    });
}
```

And in the activity class, I have a function as you suggested..

```
 @Override
  public void firstDateBack(String firstDate) {
    FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction      transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.root_chart,CategoryChart.getInstance(firstDate));
    transaction.commit();

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to update the fragment from within the fragment without referring back to the activity to renew the fragment?

Comment: I seems i wanted to do that. Going back to activity, then viewpageradapter class and then fragment, it seemed tricky for me. Can you explain how can i solve this ??

Comment: sorry not to get back till now   have you solved it...if not I'll get back to you immediately

Comment: Actually I have not solved it because of my finals. Can you help me in this? Help will be appreciated

Comment: Will do.. I'll test it first - give me a day!

Answer (score 0):

What needs to happen is your Activity adds/replaces the fragment.  The user selects the year from the spinner.  The fragment transmits the firstDate back to the Activity through an interface.  The Activity then needs to replace with a NEW fragment and pass it the firstDate to implement.

In your fragment create

(a) Three fields:

```
listener mCallback;
Activity mActivity;
public String firstDate=””;
```

(b) Interface:

```
Public interface listener(){
    public void firstDateBack(String firstDate);
}
```

(c) Method

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        mActivity=activity;
        super.onAttach(activity);
    mCallback = (listener) mActivity;
    }`
```

Then  modify your OnSelectedListener:

```
dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View spinnerTextView, int position, long id) {
        TextView myText= (TextView) spinnerTextView;
        firstDate= (String) myText.getText();
mCallback.firstDateBack(firstDate);
    }
```

In your mainactivity:

(i)  The Activity MUST  “implements CategoryChart.listener”

(ii)    Implement the interface:

```
public void bringBackString(String stringBroughtBack){

IN HERE create  a NEW CategoryChart  fragment , with a NEW transaction and pass the fragment “stringBroughtBack” e.g.
CategoryChart cc=new CategoryChart();
cc.firstDate=stringBroughtBack; 
replace and commit as usual
}
```

I have used android.app.Activity in this example and to make sure it works you may wish to use it too.  Try it and let me know how you get on

Comment: I followed your process but it is not working with spinner. It's working when I create a button instead of spinner. I have also tried another method. But that method is also working with button but not spinner.        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548297/replacing-fragment-from-inside-spinner

Comment: Bipin -  I have tested an app with a spinner in the fragment and it is firing on selection and passing info back to the activity.  When you say it is not working, what is not working?  Can you post updated code to look at.

Comment: Thankyou so much for assisting me through this. I have added my updated code as you asked above. App will crash itself when i open it if I use spinner.

Comment: Bipin - have you implemented a) b) and c) above in the fragment?  Also can you post the stacktrace so I can see the error.

Comment: I sorted out the first problem. Application hit database before value was set.  Now there's another problem. As I have spinner implementation inside a fragment, after fragment runs, spinner value gets selected, main activity is called, main activity replaces fragment, fragment runs, spinner value gets selected, main activity is called and activity replaces fragment. This goes on a loop. I there any other way to implement spinner in this case ?

Comment: Let me try it and get back to you

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you are trying to achieve.  Could you have a public boolean in the fragment set from your main and when set the spinner does not show?  So second time around in onCreateView()  have if (firstTime){spinner(view)} would not trigger spinner?